# ngx-bootstrap - Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap/component-loader'

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I'm currently working on Angular CLI applicaiton. Few hours ago I done with some part, shutdown project and now I want to run project ones again to continiue my work. But instead of succes project compile i get error on ngx-bootstrap module.

```
    ERROR in node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/dropdown/bs-dropdown.directive.d.ts(2,40): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap/component-loader'.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/dropdown/bs-dropdown.state.d.ts(2,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap/component-loader'.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/public_api.d.ts(2,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap/utils'.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/public_api.d.ts(3,95): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap/accordion'.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/public_api.d.ts(4,58): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap/alert'.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/public_api.d.ts(5,78): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap/buttons'.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/public_api.d.ts(6,83): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap/carousel'.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/public_api.d.ts(7,51): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap/collapse'.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/public_api.d.ts(8,284): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker'.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/public_api.d.ts(9,133): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap/modal'.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/public_api.d.ts(11,107): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap/pagination'.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/public_api.d.ts(12,90): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap/progressbar'.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/public_api.d.ts(13,47): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap/rating'.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/public_api.d.ts(14,102): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap/sortable'.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/public_api.d.ts(15,117): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap/tabs'.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/public_api.d.ts(16,73): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap/timepicker'.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/public_api.d.ts(17,91): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip'.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/public_api.d.ts(18,116): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap/typeahead'.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/public_api.d.ts(19,91): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap/popover'.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/public_api.d.ts(20,146): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap/utils'.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/public_api.d.ts(21,85): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap/component-loader'.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/public_api.d.ts(22,87): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap/positioning'.
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/public_api.d.ts(25,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap/locale'.
```

I tried to install ngx-bootstrap module but this does not help.
Anyone had similar problem as mine ?

Comment: how do you import ```Bs DropdownModule```? and which angular version?

Comment: Actually I'm using only import BsModalService and BsModalRef  

{BsModalRef, BsModalService} from 'ngx-bootstrap';

Angular CLI: 1.6.8
Node: 8.9.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After update @angular/cli and @angular/core to v7, problem gone.

Angular CLI: 7.0.6
Node: 8.9.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.1.0

Comment: Please mark your answer as an answer to the question

Comment: I am getting this error in Angular version 8.2 and angular/cli version 8.3

Answer (score 1):

Just had same problem, but in my case I couldn't upgrade angular cli or core, probably everything would fall to pieces... I fixed it by downgrading to

```
"ngx-bootstrap": "2.0.2"
```

previously used "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.2.0" which made these same problems. Thanks for hint tho.